# How can I separate differents enchantments from a book

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, I enchanted some books with incompatible enchantments, then, I got them all united in a single book and now I want to have all that enchantments (Knockback 2, Silk Touck and Fire Protection 1) into separate books.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to separate enchantments from a book in vanilla Minecraft. Some mods like Minefactory Reloaded offer ways to do it, but it can't be done in vanilla.

Answer (score 2):

Should you decide to use the *modded* approach mentioned by Unionhawk, [MineFactory Reloaded](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1287424-1-5-1-1-5-2-powercrystals-mods-the-updates-never) offers a machine block that can be used to separate enchantments from a book.

From the [Feed The Beast wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Auto-Disenchanter):

> The **Auto-Disenchanter** is a machine added by [MineFactory Reloaded](http://ftbwiki.org/MineFactory_Reloaded) which will extract a randomly chosen enchantment from an enchanted item and store it in a [Book](http://ftbwiki.org/Book), turning it into an [Enchanted Book](http://ftbwiki.org/Enchanted_Book). To operate, it requires you to insert an enchanted item and a book, along with a supply of power. When an item has been disenchanted, it will take some damage, which can break the item if it was already sufficiently damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Punch I, Infinity, and feather Falling IV and I used it on my bow thinking my book will give me back the unused one, but no. It does not give your Enchantments back. Try using the jumbled enchanted books on important stuff like armor and weaponry. That's all.

Answer (score -4):

You can actually separate them. Just use the enchantment book on the selected object and it will put all available enchantments on it. Any leftover enchantments will go back to the book. Therefore, you can practically separate books.

Comment: This is false. From the [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Book): "If a book is applied to an item which can't take all of its spells, the appropriate spells are transferred, while the unusable ones are lost."